# How to query the database with infromation from another query?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a mysql table with information about students and another will info about payments. I want to display a table with the student name and payment info. Is my code correct? or am I misunderstanding how it works because this results in an empty array.
I want it, for every student it found in  $data['students'] to search for the payment info with same studentid be from this year and class id be the same as $id. Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
    $data['students'] = $this->db->get_where('students', array('class_id' => $id), 40);

    foreach ($data['students']->result_array() as $student){        
        $data['student_info'] = $this->db->get_where('student_payments', array('class_id' => $id, 'student_id' => $student['id'], 'year' => date("Y")), 40);        
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Thaiscorpion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM students
JOIN student_payments on student_payments.student_id = students.student_id
WHERE students.class_id= $id"
$result = my_sql_query($query);
if($result->num_rows() >0)
{
    return $result->result_array();
}  else  {
    return array();
}
```

I personally skip the CI stuff entirely once I start joining tables, sometimes it just makes things more difficult than they need to be. The only thing I didn't see in your code is how you're passing the class_id.

Comment: Thanx for the quick response Rick, I can´t believe ive been using this so long and never seen the JOIN function for mysql querys :D thanks I'm gonna give it a try I will tell you how it went in a bit.

Comment: Thanks Rick that worked perfect here is the CI version if anyone needed it.

$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->from('students');

$this->db->where('students.class_id', $id);

$this->db->join('student_payments', 'student_payments.student_id = students.id', 'INNER');

Comment: Glad it worked. I have had some issues using CI's query builder in the past so I tend to do anything beyond just basic queries in normal PHP queries honestly, but hey if it works that's great!